# conditional track in a plot R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm using 'shiny' to make an app that plots some data, the main plot has 8 different tracks, there names are-

> 102G-long, 102G-short, 103G-long, 103G-short, 102G-heat, 103G-hit, 102G-hit-heat, 103G-hit-heat.

The long/short tracks are supposed to be optional (there is a radio button to hide them)

The plot is with a facet grid, so I just remove from the data.frame all the data relevant to the track that the user decides to hide, (of course I keep the data, I have 2 copies and only change one of them) and it automatically removes the track, the problem is if I remove both of the long, or both of the short tracks, I get this error-

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, xend, yend, size, colour

I think the problem is that when I plot I 'design' the different tracks like this-

```
ggplot(seg) + facet_grid(id~chr) + 
  geom_rect(data=subset(seg,grepl("heat$",id)),
            mapping=aes(xmin=start,ymin=0,xmax=end,ymax=log2,fill=xlog2)) +
  geom_segment(data=subset(seg,!grepl("heat$",seg$id) & !grepl("short$",seg$id) & !grepl("long$",seg$id)),
               mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,log2>0,color=log2>0)) +
  geom_segment(data=subset(seg,grepl("short$",id)),
               mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0)) +
  geom_segment(data=subset(seg,grepl("long$",id)),
               mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0)) +
```

and if I remove both of the short for example, then there is no data in this line -

```
geom_segment(data=subset(seg,grepl("short$",id)),
               mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0)) +
```

Is there a way to put this line in a condition so it will be executed only if there is some data referring to short? or maybe a different way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you get an error? ggplot will probably execute fine if your passing an empty data.frame

Comment: Like I wrote, I do get an error- Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, xend, yend, size, colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is very simple, I feel stupid, I simply created a graph object, and added thing to the object with conditions, like this-

```
temp_plot <- ggplot(seg) + facet_grid(id~chr) + 
  geom_rect(data=subset(seg,grepl("heat$",id)),
            mapping=aes(xmin=start,ymin=0,xmax=end,ymax=log2,fill=xlog2)) +
  geom_segment(data=subset(seg,!grepl("heat$",seg$id) & !grepl("short$",seg$id) & !grepl("long$",seg$id)),
               mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,log2>0,color=log2>0))
if(!("102G-short" %in% input$hide_tracks & "103G-short" %in% input$hide_tracks)) {
  temp_plot <- temp_plot + geom_segment(data=subset(seg,grepl("short$",id)),
                                        mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0))
}

if(!("102G-long" %in% input$hide_tracks & "103G-long" %in% input$hide_tracks)) {
  temp_plot <- temp_plot + geom_segment(data=subset(seg,grepl("long$",id)),
                                        mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0))
}
temp_plot <- temp_plot + scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-3,3),low="darkblue",mid="white",high="darkred",na.value="white",midpoint=0) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  ylab("") + 
  ylim(c(-2,2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y)
temp_plot
```